# How to remove pepper noise from a non-handwritten scanned document(.tif) in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am unable to find a method to detect the text area in the document and apply a filter to the rest of the image to clear it from any noise. Please refer to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU4m6.png) image. If I do apply a filter to the image anyway, the text doesn't remain visible anymore.
Is there an algorithm in MATLAB that can help me find the textarea and treat it separately?

Comment: you can either use median filter to remove noise OR morphological operations but this image has large amount of noise and it will affect text also.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly reduce the amount of noise by applying erosion, followed by a gaussian blur (σ=2; the image will be converted to grayscale) followed by conversion back to binary.

Erosion alone will reduce the amount of noise significantly:
[image: Image after application of erosion]

After application of gaussian blur and re-conversion into binary, the noise will be further reduced. Note that very small text (like the sub-headline) will be also degraded:
[image: Image after application of erosion, blurring with gaussian blur and re-conversion to binary]

All three needed operations seem to be already implemented in MatLab: See [Erosion](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html); [Gaussian Blur](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html) and [Thresholding](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html). However, note that for the example automatic (histogram based) thresholding was used to determine the optimal threshold.